# pointer being freed was not allocated, without any new usage

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I'm going through a piece of code here. For testing purposes it shows a window (`QWidget`) when executed.

When I hit close it returns:

```
my_object(7082,0x7fff7a538000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5199b9b8: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Where `my_object` is an instance of the class instantiated at a QMainWindow.

There is no `new` usage in all code I wrote. And also no `delete` call. How is that (`pointer being freed`) possible? I though not using explicit `new` I'll be outside the dangerous zone.

What's the best way to approach this (`pointer being freed was not allocated`) issue. I'll go by disabling some parts or, in other words, try/error approach.

Comment: Did you call `delete` on it?

Comment: No `delete` call also.

Comment: @LogicStuff, could you please be a little more verbose?

Comment: Then you are going to need to produce a [mcve]

Comment: *I though not using new explicit I'll be outside the dangerous zone.* I got triggered by this. People need to stop saying *Never use new and delete in modern C++* and instead say *You should practice safe C++.*

Comment: There are many reasons why this can happen did you use any setParent ?

Comment: We can't find the problems in code that we can't see.

Comment: @Marco, no `setParent` at all. Would you mind to point one or two reasons this can happen?

Comment: All qobjects in Qt take as last parameter the parent object, parent object means that when parent is freed all children are also freed (using delete). In your case it looks like the window you are closing is being freed and tries to release some children and one of them does not exist.

Comment: *What's the best way to approach this* making a [mcve]

Comment: @Marco, thank you for remembering about that. Almost always, when I have this problem it's matter of changing the order of member declaration in the .h file - it was not different this time.

Comment: You mean that the compiler can/should tell me if members are declared in wrong order? I'm on MacOS El Captain, I guess with the latest compiler (clang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boy,

Check the order of member declaration in all classes involved.